# Talend tRunJob returns NoClassDefFoundError with child job list

Tags: java, talend, noclassdeffounderror

I have a job built with childjob in it.The child job will be called iteratively and "Use an independent process to run subjob" option is disabled. When this job is exported as a shell and run the job works fine. But when all these jars are pulled in to eclipse and deployed as a war inside the JVM I am getting below error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Child job return 1. It doesn't terminate normally.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: loadbalancer/loadbalancer_0_1/loadBalancer

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: loadbalancer.loadbalancer_0_1.loadBalancer
   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
   at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

The library contained all the jars including the chld_job jar.

Thanks,
Jose.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why am I getting a NoClassDefFoundError in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java)

Comment: Yes, more or less. The class is not found in runtime, but I can't fix it witht Talend IDE. Thanks anyway